# Excel - putting values in different columns based on separator

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a large string copied into a cell in Excel. The format is like this:

```
key,key;
```

**Example:**

```
Key 1,key 2;key 3,key 4;key 5,key 6;
```

I want to split the keys using '`;`' and then split each string by '`,`' and copy values in different columns.

```
  A           B
Key 1       key 2
Key 3       key 4
Key 5       key 6
```

Is it possible to do this in excel without using any programming language?

Comment: If it's just a one time operation, I would copy that text, put it in a text editor. Do a find and replace, and change all the ; s to new lines. Then copy the multi line text back to excel. From there, all you need to do is 'text to columns' and use , as the separator.

Comment: @BarisTasdelen: It actually worked. a quick google search helped me with `text to columns` & I  got the data in right format. Simple and effective